# Strech video Flow player

Tags: flash, video, scaling, flowplayer, video-player

I need to strech video disregarding aspect ratio, I need the video to fill all my height and width of the window. Currently flow player preserves aspect ratio and it looks like this (see screenshot):

[image]

My code for initializing is:

```
newplayer = flowplayer("#flowPlayer", {
      autoplay: true,
        bgcolor: "#225533",
         live: true,
      engine:'flash',

      clip: {
        sources: [
          { type: "application/x-mpegurl", src: url }
        ]
      }

    });
```

I have tried to put scaling `'scale'` into the clip and above the clip but it still doesn't strech the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [documentation](https://flowplayer.org/docs/encoding.html#general-advice)
 It says that flash does not read 'ratio'